# Problema insertando el array de datos para marcadores google maps

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-v3

Tengo una tabla `html` que se crea con un `php` llamando a la base de datos

Ejemplo:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
$query = "select id, name from pizza";
$result = $conn->query($query)
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo " <td><button id='button' onclick='SomeFunction()'> View stores </button></td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>

<!-- here is the map -->
<div id="map" class="mapcss">
<script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=myMap"></script>
</div>
```

y tengo la función para crear el mapa en un .js

```
    function myMap() {
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.4545832, -70.6541925);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 12
});
}
```

También una función para agregar los marcadores, mi problema es como llenar este array para colocar los marcadores en el mapa

```
function SomeFunction() {

    var locations = [  
           *Data from db here*
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
     }
    }
```

Comment: Santiago en el html haces una selección de id y nombre, los datos deberían incluir latitud y longitud, para posicionar los marcadores.

Comment: El problema es que, no es solo una latitud y longitud por cada "nombre"
Imagina que cada id y nombre se refiere a una cadena de pizzerias y lo que busco hacer es con un boton es desplegar todos los locales

Comment: Ok, puedes añadir más info a los marcadores, pero necesitas latitud y longitud entre los datos que traes en la consulta.

Comment: el problema es que por cada id de pizzeria que hay en la tabla, existen n posibles locaciones.

como puedo traer la info al momento de apretar el boton?

Comment: Santiago aquí tienes una guía de cómo traer marcadores con PHP y MySQL [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps?hl=es]. Por otro lado, deberías hacer la consulta buscando aquellas pizzerías que se encuentren en un radio de x distancia del centro del mapa (se hace con formulas trigonométricas en función de latitud y longitud), puedes hacerlo con un ajax y rellenar la variable PHP que traes en el onsuccess del ajax, a partir de aquí ya puedes usar el ejemplo del enlace.

Comment: Mi problema no es como traer marcadores, como mencione en la pregunta, es como traer con el botón, desde la base de datos, los distintos puntos hacia la variable en la función.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de pasar los datos es crear un array en PHP al recorrer los datos:

```
$markers = array ();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $marker = array();
  $marker["lat"] = $row["lat"];
  $marker["lon"] = $row["lon"];
  $markers[] = $marker;

  echo ... //lo que quieras mostrar
}
```

El array `$markers` acumulará los marcadores. En `javascript` pasas el valor de este array al de localizaciones.

```
var locations = <? = $markers; ?>;
```

Como tu función carga el mapa en el onclick, utilizará los marcadores que tengas en el array.

Otra forma de hacerlo si tienes datos diferentes en varios botones, que creo puede ser tu caso, es pasando los datos en el onclick del botón, ya que el array se sobrescribe en este caso:

Dentro del `while`:

```
 $s_markers = implode(",",$markers);
  ...onclick="SomeFunction('<?php echo $s_markers;?>');"...
```

Y en `javascript`:

```
function SomeFunctin(a){
  var locations = a.split(',');
 ...
}
```

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta Santiago.

En el enlace que te pasé en los comentarios hay otro modo de hacerlo con los marcadores en formato XML creado en PHP, pero no contiene la parte del onclick.